# How I can change my region when I have few Apple ID balance?

Tags: ios-appstore, iphone

How I can change my region when I have a low Apple ID balance?
I had $50 Apple ID balance now I have 0.22. I want to change my region to download sonic runners but I can't. What are my options?

Comment: create new Account.

Answer (score 1):

If you are prepared to sacrifice the remaining balance, contact Apple support and they will remove it and you can then change regions.